# Add xhrFields to dropzone.js to send session data across domains

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors, dropzone.js

I just installed dropzone (http://www.dropzonejs.com/) on one of my sites to upload Images per drag an drop. It works good but I now try to upload Images from a subdomain of this page. 
It all works, but the session data is not send to the upload.php. On other ajax calls I just can add *xhrFields: { withCredentials:true }* and it will work as I wish. But in dropzone this Option does Nothing.

So can someone help me, so I can finish my function?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english (German Guy)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, it is really simple. Wrote the developer of dropzone.js and he helped me out.
I don’t Need the xhrFields Argument. Just add *withCredentials: true* to the dropzone Options and it will work as expected.